# MySqli update data in column through php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i am trying to update a field inside my table to reflect the changes made in html, the data is posted into php however the changes are not being reflected in the database, despite no error showing up

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', '', 'car_rental') or die  ("SQL is Off");


$sku = $_POST['firstsku'];
$days = $_POST['days'];
$user = $_SESSION["userEmail"];

mysqli_select_db($db,"car_rental");
$query = " UPDATE products SET rented=1 WHERE sku='$sku'";
$query1 = "UPDATE `users` SET `rented` = 'pie 32' WHERE `users`.`email` = 'user'";

$result1 = mysqli_query($db, $query1);
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
?>
```

the second query result1 is the one where i am not getting any data change in the database

Comment: Please accept the edit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$combine = $days.'-'.$sku;
$query1 = "UPDATE users SET rented = '$combine' WHERE users.email = '$user'";
```

Combine two values using `-` and then try to update.

Comment: thanks it worked, now to figure out how to represent this on user account, PS i didnt downvote

Comment: @AhmedBakir *now to figure out how to represent this on user account,* what is this?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `$user` inside your query.Change your second query with this :

```
$query1 = "UPDATE `users` SET `rented` = 'pie 32' WHERE `users`.`email` = '$user'";
```

Comment: hi thanks i corrected that and now i'm trying to input the sku and days data like this, $query1 = "UPDATE `users` SET `rented` = '$days', '$sku' WHERE `users`.`email` = '$user'";  is this the correct way?

Comment: @AhmedBakir Query should be:
`$query1 = "UPDATE users SET rented = '$days', sku='$sku' WHERE users.email = '$user'";`

Comment: strange, it still isnt reflecting any changes on the database

Comment: @AhmedBakir make changes as i told

Comment: What do you want? @AhmedBakir

Comment: @AhmedBakir if you want to update multiple columns then you have to do what i told like this: `$query1 = "UPDATE users SET rented = '$days', sku='$sku' WHERE users.email = '$user'";`

Comment: @Mr.Engineer Engineer i want to add the SKU and Days data into the field called rented

Comment: days and sku are separate?

Comment: @PathikVejani i only want to update the column of the active user, thats why i am using the $user, also no error

Comment: @AhmedBakir try my answer. may be it what you want

Answer (score 0):

Query should be like

```
$query1 = "UPDATE `users` SET `rented` = 'pie 32' WHERE `users`.`email` = '".$user."' ";
```